# Optimize search in file with bash and php

Tags: php, bash, optimization

I'm working on a script that fetch a file that contain too many data ( 1 million line ) , and for each line i have to look into a file that's too big (7 Go ).

Here is what i tried :

```
$fichier_src = fopen($fichier_src_path, 'r');
if ($fichier_src) {
            $result = fgetcsv($fichier_src, 1000 , ";"); // for skip the first line
            while ( ($result = fgetcsv($fichier_src, 1000 , ";")) !== FALSE) {
                if( isset($result[0]) && $result[0] != ''){
                    $search = $result[0];
                    shell_exec(" LC_ALL=C fgrep -A 5 -B 5 '$search' $fichier_search | LC_ALL=C fgrep -A 5 -B 5 '$critere'  >> $fichier_tmp "); 
                    $fichier_search_tmp = fopen($fichier_tmp, "r") or die("impossible d\'ouvrir le fichier");
                    if ($fichier_search_tmp) {
                        while (!feof($fichier_search_tmp)) {
                            $s_result = fgets($fichier_search_tmp, 4096);
                            if( $s_result == $search ){
                                echo "search : $search - s_result : $s_result \n ";
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        fclose($fichier_search_tmp);
                        unlink($fichier_tmp);// delete the file
                    }
                }
            }

        fclose($fichier_src);
    }
```

I tried my best to make it faster but it took too much time.

plz any suggestions !!

Comment: Put the data in a database

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: Maybe you could consider use command `parallel` in shell scipt, then invoke the script using php command `shell_exec`